# Console returns SSML error when adding parameter to emphasis tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssml, amazon-polly

I am working on a Python script to convert SSML into audio for an application.  I already have the text conversion working, but I am figuring out the SSML part by experimenting in the console.

From the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/supported-ssml.html#emphasis-tag there is an example using the emphasis tag with the level parameter:

```
<speak>
     I already told you I <emphasis level="strong">really like</emphasis> that person.
</speak>
```

When I enter my SSML into the console:

```
<speak>
Hi there.  My name is Joanna.
<p>This is line 2</p>
I am really <emphasis level=“strong”>excited</emphasis> to be here with you today.
</speak>
```

After pressing the “Listen to audio” button, the console returns an error

> the input text contains invalid SSML syntax.  Fix the SSML syntax and then try again.

If I remove the level keyword so the SSML reads

```
<speak>
I am really <emphasis>excited</emphasis> to be here with you today.
</speak>
```

it is converted correctly.

The example provided in the Polly documentation works, but I cannot figure out why my text has an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, that typing into the text input box in the console on an iPad will change the quotes if you have "Smart Punctuation" turned on, and the quotes inserted using that feature will break the SSML processing engine.

On the iPad, go to General->keyboards->Smart Punctuation.  If it is turned on, disable it.  It makes no difference if you are using the on-screen keyboard or a hardware keyboard.  If this setting is enabled, the quotes are replaced.

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't the case on this answer, but you need to keep in mind the support of these tags. For example, the emphasis tag is only available (by the time I write this answer) in the standard form, not the neural form.

[click here to see the supported task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/supportedtags.html)

Answer (score 0):

the quotes around "level" look weird. You've probably copied and pasted from another editor? Please make sure you use proper quotes and it should work :)

Comment: They do look weird now that you mention it, but no - they were typed directly into the text box in the console.  Not sure if it is important or not, but I am doing it on an ipad.

Comment: That's probably it. They don't look like plain ASCII quotes.